# fetching the drawing done on canvas using getRootView

Tags: android

I am using `MyView` for drawing content on a canvas using `FingerPaint API` demo app. I want to capture whatever I have written on the canvas. But when I use `View v1 = myview.getRootView()` it is returning only the blank canvas and not the content. I want to save my drawing in SDCard. Following is my code. Let me know what do i need to change

```
v1 = myview.getRootView();
System.out.println("v1 value = "+v1);
v1.buildDrawingCache(true);
v1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
           MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
//v1.layout(0, 0, v1.getMeasuredWidth(), v1.getMeasuredHeight()); 
v1.layout(0, 0, 100, 100); 

//Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
myview.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
System.out.println("BITMAP VALue = "+myview.mBitmap);

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "test.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

`myview` is an object of class `MyView` that extends `View`.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use the myview object to get the current view/canvas

```
myview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = myview.getDrawingCache();
```

for immutable image use this

```
Bitmap b = myview.getDrawingCache().copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

and then you can save this bitmap as image file